# Who is the god of craft?

Tags: vedas, puranas, gods, itihasa, architecture

In greek myths, there is one god named Hephaestus. He is the god/patron of craftsmen and forges and blacksmiths etc.

Is there a similar god in Hinduism? I think that there is one, just he isn't very well known. And how should I pray to him?

Thanks

Comment: Vishvakarma or Vishvakarman (विश्वकर्मा) is a craftsman deity and the divine architect of the devas in contemporary Hinduism. In the early texts, the craftsman deity was known as Tvastar and the word "Vishvakarma" was originally used as an epithet for any powerful deity. However, in many later traditions, Vishvakarma became the name of the craftsman god.

Comment: Ok. Just_Do_It , can you please tell me if there is any sloka I can use to ask him for help? And if you make this as an answer I will accept it. Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in my comment above [Vishvakarma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishvakarma) or Vishvakarman (विश्वकर्मा) is a craftsman deity and the divine architect of the devas in contemporary Hinduism. In the early texts, the craftsman deity was known as Tvastar and the word "Vishvakarma" was originally used as an epithet for any powerful deity. However, in many later traditions, Vishvakarma became the name of the craftsman god.

As for the other part of your question you can chant the [Vishwakarma Stotra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPTwaWl6SYE)/[Ashtakam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRfFRtxWccg) which is dedicated to Lord Sri Vishwakarma who is the first engineer of this world. Even the map of this world was decided by him, it is said.

Benefits of performing Vishwakarma Puja is to achieve success in career, fulfill wishes related to movable assets, helps in buying a house or office, enhance productivity at work, securing working environment, removes negativity that hampered work.

You can also chant the 108 names of him:

> Om Vishwakarmane Namah
>
> Om Vishwatmane Namah
>
> Om Vishvasamaya Namah
>
> Om Vishwadharaya Namah
>
> Om Vishwadharmaya Namah
>
> Om Virje Namah
>
> Om Vishvekshvaraya Namah
>
> Om Vishnave Namah
>
> Om Vishvadharaya Namah
>
> Om Vishwakaraya Namah
>
> Om Vastoshpataye Namah
>
> Om Vishvabhanraya Namah
>
> Om Vermine Namah
>
> Om Vardaya Namah
>
> Om Vishveshadhipataye Namah
>
> Om Vitalay Namah
>
> Om Vishbhunjaya Namah
>
> Om Vishwavyapine Namah
>
> Om Devaya Namah
>
> Om Dharmine Namah
>
> Om Dheeray Namah
>
> Om Dharay Namah
>
> Om Paratmane Namah
>
> Om Purushay Namah
>
> Om Dharmatmane Namah
>
> Om Shwetangaya Namah
>
> Om Shwetvastraya Namah
>
> Om Hansvahanay Namah
>
> Om Trigunatmane Namah
>
> Om Satyaatmane Namah
>
> Om Gunvallabhai Namah
>
> Om Bhukalpaya Namah
>
> Om Bhulenkay Namah
>
> Om Bhuvalekaya Namah
>
> Om Chaturbhujaya Namah
>
> Om Vishwarupaya Namah
>
> Om Universal Namah
>
> Om Anantaya Namah
>
> Om Antaya Namah
>
> Om Ahmane Namah
>
> Om Atalaya Namah
>
> Om Aghratmane Namah
>
> Om Anantmukhay Namah
>
> Om Anantbhujay Namah
>
> Om Anantayakshuya Namah
>
> Om Anantakalpaya Namah
>
> Om Anantashaktibhute Namah
>
> Om Atisukshmay Namah
>
> Om Trinetraya Namah
>
> Om Kambigharaya Namah
>
> Om Gyanmudraya Namah
>
> Om Sutratmane Namah
>
> Om Sutradharay Namah
>
> Om Mahalokaya Namah
>
> Om Janalokaya Namah
>
> Om Tasholokaya Namah
>
> Om Satyakokaya Namah
>
> Om Sutalaya Namah
>
> Om Salatalaya Namah
>
> Om Mahatalaya Namah
>
> Om Rasatalaya Namah
>
> Om Patalaya Namah
>
> Om Manushpine Namah
>
> Om Tvashte Namah
>
> Om Devgya Namah
>
> Om Poornaprabhaya Namah
>
> Om Hrdayavasine Namah
>
> Om Roguedamnath Namah
>
> Om Devdharai Namah
>
> Om Sthir Karaya Namah
>
> Om Vasapatre Namah
>
> Om Purnanandaya Namah
>
> Om Sanandaya Namah
>
> Om Sarveshvaranya Namah
>
> Om Parmeshwaraya Namah
>
> Om Tejatmane Namah
>
> Om Paramatmane Namah
>
> Om Kritipataye Namah
>
> Om Brihad Smanaya Namah
>
> Om Brahmanaya Namah
>
> Om Bhuvanpataye Namah
>
> Om Tribhuvanath Namah
>
> Om Satatnath Namah
>
> Om Sarvadaye Namah
>
> Om Karshapaya Namah
>
> Om Harshay Namah
>
> Om Sukhkatre Namah
>
> Om Dukhhartre Namah
>
> Om Nirvikalpaya Namah
>
> Om Nirvidhay Namah
>
> Om Nismay Namah
>
> Om Niradharaya Namah
>
> Om Nikakaraya Namah
>
> Om Mahdurlabhai Namah
>
> Om Nimohay Namah
>
> Om Shantimurtaya Namah
>
> Om Shantidatre Namah
>
> Om Mokshadatre Namah
>
> Om Sthaviraya Namah
>
> Om Sukshmaya Namah
>
> Om Nirmohay Namah
>
> Om Dharadharaya Namah
>
> Om Sthutismay Namah
>
> Om Vishwarakshakaya Namah
>
> Om Durlabhay Namah
>
> Om Swarglokaya Namah
>
> Om Panchavaktraya Namah
>
> Om Vishvallabhai Namah.

> 1. ॐ विश्वकर्मणे नमः
> 2. ॐ विश्वात्मने नमः
> 3. ॐ विश्वस्माय नमः
> 4. ॐ विश्वधाराय नमः
> 5. ॐ विश्वधर्माय नमः
> 6. ॐ विरजे नमः
> 7. ॐ विश्वेक्ष्वराय नमः
> 8. ॐ विष्णवे नमः
> 9. ॐ विश्वधराय नमः
> 10. ॐ विश्वकराय नमः
> 11. ॐ वास्तोष्पतये नमः
> 12. ॐ विश्वभंराय नमः
> 13. ॐ वर्मिणे नमः
> 14. ॐ वरदाय नमः
> 15. ॐ विश्वेशाधिपतये नमः
> 16. ॐ वितलाय नमः
> 17. ॐ विशभुंजाय नमः
> 18. ॐ विश्वव्यापिने नमः
> 19. ॐ देवाय नमः
> 20. ॐ धार्मिणे नमः
> 21. ॐ धीराय नमः
> 22. ॐ धराय नमः
> 23. ॐ परात्मने नमः
> 24. ॐ पुरुषाय नमः
> 25. ॐ धर्मात्मने नमः
> 26. ॐ श्वेतांगाय नमः
> 27. ॐ श्वेतवस्त्राय नमः
> 28. ॐ हंसवाहनाय नमः
> 29. ॐ त्रिगुणात्मने नमः
> 30. ॐ सत्यात्मने नमः
> 31. ॐ गुणवल्लभाय नमः
> 32. ॐ भूकल्पाय नमः
> 33. ॐ भूलेंकाय नमः
> 34. ॐ भुवलेकाय नमः
> 35. ॐ चतुर्भुजय नमः
> 36. ॐ विश्वरुपाय नमः
> 37. ॐ विश्वव्यापक नमः
> 38. ॐ अनन्ताय नमः
> 39. ॐ अन्ताय नमः
> 40. ॐ आह्माने नमः
> 41. ॐ अतलाय नमः
> 42. ॐ आघ्रात्मने नमः
> 43. ॐ अनन्तमुखाय नमः
> 44. ॐ अनन्तभूजाय नमः
> 45. ॐ अनन्तयक्षुय नमः
> 46. ॐ अनन्तकल्पाय नमः
> 47. ॐ अनन्तशक्तिभूते नमः
> 48. ॐ अतिसूक्ष्माय नमः
> 49. ॐ त्रिनेत्राय नमः
> 50. ॐ कंबीघराय नमः
> 51. ॐ ज्ञानमुद्राय नमः
> 52. ॐ सूत्रात्मने नमः
> 53. ॐ सूत्रधराय नमः
> 54. ॐ महलोकाय नमः
> 55. ॐ जनलोकाय नमः
> 56. ॐ तषोलोकाय नमः
> 57. ॐ सत्यकोकाय नमः
> 58. ॐ सुतलाय नमः
> 59. ॐ सलातलाय नमः
> 60. ॐ महातलाय नमः
> 61. ॐ रसातलाय नमः
> 62. ॐ पातालाय नमः
> 63. ॐ मनुषपिणे नमः
> 64. ॐ त्वष्टे नमः
> 65. ॐ देवज्ञाय नमः
> 66. ॐ पूर्णप्रभाय नमः
> 67. ॐ ह्रदयवासिने नमः
> 68. ॐ दुष्टदमनाथ नमः
> 69. ॐ देवधराय नमः
> 70. ॐ स्थिर कराय नमः
> 71. ॐ वासपात्रे नमः
> 72. ॐ पूर्णानंदाय नमः
> 73. ॐ सानन्दाय नमः
> 74. ॐ सर्वेश्वरांय नमः
> 75. ॐ परमेश्वराय नमः
> 76. ॐ तेजात्मने नमः
> 77. ॐ परमात्मने नमः
> 78. ॐ कृतिपतये नमः
> 79. ॐ बृहद् स्मणय नमः
> 80. ॐ ब्रह्मांडाय नमः
> 81. ॐ भुवनपतये नमः
> 82. ॐ त्रिभुवनाथ नमः
> 83. ॐ सतातनाथ नमः
> 84. ॐ सर्वादये नमः
> 85. ॐ कर्षापाय नमः
> 86. ॐ हर्षाय नमः
> 87. ॐ सुखकत्रे नमः
> 88. ॐ दुखहर्त्रे नमः
> 89. ॐ निर्विकल्पाय नमः
> 90. ॐ निर्विधाय नमः
> 91. ॐ निस्माय नमः
> 92. ॐ निराधाराय नमः
> 93. ॐ निकाकाराय नमः
> 94. ॐ महदुर्लभाय नमः
> 95. ॐ निमोहाय नमः
> 96. ॐ शांतिमुर्तय नमः
> 97. ॐ शांतिदात्रे नमः
> 98. ॐ मोक्षदात्रे नमः
> 99. ॐ स्थवीराय नमः
> 100. ॐ सूक्ष्माय नमः
> 101. ॐ निर्मोहय नमः
> 102. ॐ धराधराय नमः
> 103. ॐ स्थूतिस्माय नमः
> 104. ॐ विश्वरक्षकाय नमः
> 105. ॐ दुर्लभाय नमः
> 106. ॐ स्वर्गलोकाय नमः
> 107. ॐ पंचवकत्राय नमः
> 108. ॐ विश्वलल्लभाय नमः।

Comment: Can you provide a link of English Translation of the sloka, For people who don't know Hindi :-)

Comment: @Shashaank updated the answer for you :)

Comment: Thank you soo much :-)